# Which airlines offer indemnity forms?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry, fines

I read on this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/155099/1810) by [Anish Sheela](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67804/anish-sheela):

> Sign indemnity form saying that you accept personal responsibility to pay the fine imposed to the airline, in case you are denied.

Which airlines offer indemnity forms? Do all airlines have it, or just a few ones?

---

From [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/157010/1810) by [Zach Lipton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13650/zach-lipton), at least Qatar Airways has it:

[image]

([image source](https://twitter.com/tparsi/status/825479398803566592/photo/1))

Comment: This question is quite broad, do you have a specific airline in mind? Seeing as there are around 5,000 airlines in the world...

Comment: Requests for open-ended lists where every answer is equally valid are a poor fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Asking 50 questions for the top 50 airlines doesn't seem that great either.

Comment: The answer referred to in the question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157007/how-much-would-an-airline-be-fined-if-the-immigration-officers-of-the-destinatio/157010#157010 states ‘such forms are quite uncommon’. Have you tried searching the airlines you’re interested in?

Comment: @Traveller thanks, yes that's why I was fearing the list would be short anyway. I would like to know ahead of time for the main airlines in case I need to buy a ticket at the counter at the last minute before the check-in closes ([as it happened recently](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155092/1810)).

Comment: I doubt airlines advertise this because its not something they will want used regularly.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt given the time limits there, are you sure that an indemnity form would help at all, as it might need to be authorised by someone higher up than checkin.

Comment: @Moo this makes the question even more interesting. Regarding your second comment, depends on how last minute I am and how far the boss is

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that asking 50 questions doesn't seem great doesn't mean that a list question is no longer a poor fit. Sometimes Stack Exchange sites are just the wrong place for a particular question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All airlines should have the indemnity forms. But they will allow you to use that only if they are reasonably sure that you will be admitted to the destination country. Airline will have to pay fine, whether you sign this or not. They will strongly try to recover from you any losses they incur, as they have documentation that you agree to pay.

An example would be the passport is slightly damaged, but it won't be usually a problem, airline could offer the form to cover the risk. Another example would be if you are trying to board to USA without a visa, no amount of convincing will get you this form.

Answer (score 1):

Thai AirAsia has it (at least in 2006). Example from https://www.flickr.com/photos/zhaffsky/352652268:

[image]